# Change /proc/N/comm with exec -a

Tags: linux, shell, process, ps

I'm using `exec -a process-name my-command` to launch `my-command` with its name changed to `process-name`. This change does work when viewed in htop, but when I use `ps -C process-name` it won't find anything because it reads from `/proc/N/comm` and that always remains the original name: `my-command`.

Is there a way to change the value so that it's visible for ps? Please note that using different flags for ps is not an option here.

Comment: `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` has a nul-separated and nul-terminated string of the modified command-line, that is, if you run `exec -a dream sleep 60` then `$> xxd /proc/<PID>/cmdline` outputs `00000000: 6472 6561 6d00 3630 00                   dream.60.`

Comment: If you want to retrieve that original cmdline, you could do `IFS= read -r -d $'\0' cmd < <(cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline) && echo $cmd` in bash.

Comment: You could create a symlink to your executable with the desired name and run that instead of the binary.